# Locating the object path for a GATT server in BlueZ

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluez

Making a Bluetooth GATT server on a Linux machine is done using BlueZ. The preferred way to use modern (5.50) BlueZ is through the dbus API.

The [documentation](https://github.com/RadiusNetworks/bluez/blob/master/doc/gatt-api.txt#L4) on this topic states:

> GATT local and remote services share the same high-level D-Bus API.
>   Local refers to GATT based service exported by a BlueZ plugin or an
>   external application. Remote refers to GATT services exported by the
>   peer.

I am interpreting this as:

> Both **local services** (Linux machine is the server, other devices connect to it via Bluetooth) and **remote services** (Linux machine is the client, it connects to other devices via Bluetooth) are represented on dbus

That sets the base assumption for the question.

The bluez source code provides an [example-gatt-server](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/example-gatt-server?h=5.50). An example you can execute an it will just work and turn your Linux machine in a GATT server.

In that example an [arbitrarily named dbus object](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/test/example-gatt-server?h=5.50#n83) is referenced. It's name is `/org/bluez/example/service`

From the documentation I would expect then that once the `./example-gatt-server` is run successfully there should be a `/org/bluez/example/service` somewhere.

That is not the case:

```
~$ busctl tree org.bluez
└─/org
  └─/org/bluez
    └─/org/bluez/hci0
```

I am confirming with an external device that the Linux machine is acting as the GATT server, but `/org/bluez/example/service` isn't listed.

Why isn't `/org/bluez/example/service` found as an object under `org.bluez`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was also getting puzzled with this and i found that we are not able to see the dbus object as this example does not define a well-known/requested-name for this service on the dbus.

As per [busctl documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/busctl.html#Commands) for being able to query the service, you would need to have a name associated with it. While this example Gatt server does not have one.

> Shows an object tree of one or more services. If SERVICE is specified,
>   show object tree of the specified services only. Otherwise, show all
>   object trees of all services on the bus that acquired at least one
>   well-known name.

Although you can either use sudo dbus-monitor --system for monitoring the object being registered or can request a name from dbus by calling request_name on bus before creating the Application object in gatt server example code. You can check an example service with a requested name [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34482691/register-a-hello-world-dbus-service-object-and-method-using-python).

```py
bus.request_name(BUS_NAME)
named_bus = dbus.service.BusName(BUS_NAME, bus=bus)
```

You need to also give permission on system bus for publishing by editing /etc/dbus-1/system.conf and add your service name as follows:

```xml
<policy user="root">
  <allow own="com.example.gattServer"/>
</policy>
```